# How to resolve 'The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "Sheet1$" ' error?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, oledbconnection

I am using excel data import to sql table in my .net application, however i am getting following error while saving the data :

My code :

> ```
> protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     string FileName = lblFileName.Text;
>     string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
>     string FolderPath = Server.MapPath (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"]);
>     string CommandText = "";
>     switch (Extension)
>     {
>         case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
>             CommandText = "spx_ImportFromExcel03";
>             break;
>         case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
>             CommandText = "spx_ImportFromExcel07";
>             break;
>     }
>     //Read Excel Sheet using Stored Procedure
>     //And import the data into Database Table
>     String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
>     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
>     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>     cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
>     cmd.Parameters.Add("@SheetName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSheets.SelectedItem.Text;
>     cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FolderPath + FileName;
>     cmd.Parameters.Add("@HDR", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text;
>     cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTable.Text;   
>     cmd.Connection = con;
>     try
>     {
>         con.Open();
>         object count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>         lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
>         lblMessage.Text = count.ToString() + " records inserted.";  
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;     
>         lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;  
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         con.Close();
>         con.Dispose();
>         Panel1.Visible = true;
>         Panel2.Visible = false;
> ```

```
    }
}
```

and i am using connections strings for excel formats in web.config as :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'"/>
```

i could not figure out this error. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read excel file in c# code you should have microsoft oledb provider.Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is needed for reading file having format xlsx and Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is for xls format files.C# code for reading an excel file is shown below.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Filename.xls") + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"); 
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
            con.Open(); 
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            string col0 = ""; 
            string col1 = ""; 
            string col2 = ""; 
            while (dr.Read()) 
            { 
                col0 =Convert.ToString(dr[ 0]); 
                col1 =Convert.ToString(dr[ 0]); 
                col2 =Convert.ToString(dr[ 0]); 
                /*******************************
               Write Statements to Insert values of each rows into table 
                *********************************/
            } 
                con.Close(); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good article for import data form excel to database.[Import Excel to Sql](http://www.developer2blog.com/post/2012/04/20/Import-Data-From-Excel-Sheet.aspx)
Do as all instructed at there and you will be successful.

Comment: And change connections strings as per for excel 2007 or grater...
Else every thing good.
Mr. Sagar had written a nice article for importing data from Excel sheet.

Comment: Thanks Niyati.
And as Niyati said you have to use only one connection, as follow
`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";`
This will work perfectly...